# How to use Object caching on View page MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, objectcache

I am working `MVC project`. I am  having access of view page only in one project which I load using `view engine`.

Now I want to use `object caching` on `view page` as I do not want to call service method every time.

Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your View like this :

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10)]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            ViewData.Model = _dataContext.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I already mentioned that I do not have access of Controll or action method. I use view page only using partial view engine. Moreover, I call service method from my View using EngineContext. I want to put that part only in caching.